# How can I detect branch A has been merged into B by merge --squash?

Tags: git, github

I made three commits on Branch A

```
git checkout Branch B
git merge --squash A
git commit -m "B:merge A into B by squash"
```

How can I detect branch A has been merged into B by squash?

Comment: The whole point of `merge --squash` is that it isn't recorded as a merge. It's just a regular commit that happens to produce the same result a merge would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git-branch`'s `--merged` parameter give you branch list that merged with specific branch or commit. So you can check by that command:

```
git branch --merged B
```

If branch A is in list, so yes, it's merged into branch B.

Comment: I don't believe that command works when the `--squash` parameter is used.